For any given project built using SBT, is there any way, by creating a plugin/other ways, to get and STORE the details of modules and dependencies
I have a sample SBT built JAVA project Apache Pekko v1.0.0
https://github.com/apache/pekko/tree/v1.0.0
I need to setup automation in such a way that I get the name of the modules in this project, or any SBT project, and the dependencies in each module.
We can get all these details from running "sbt dependencyTree" but I need to store all the details in JSON format to be used henceforth.
For now, I have tried to create custom plugins that could be appneded to the build.sbt file, and just like Maven session, be able to extract till Nth level of dependencies.
So far only errors.

How about using the output of dependencyList
